# htaccess redirect to url with a pound sign

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Should this redirect inside .htaccess work:

```
Redirect 301 http://test.com/test http://test.com/#test
```

?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This exanple will not work. Right answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14281857/1447182.

Comment: the example you reference does not contain any information about html characters like #