# 301 redirect not working , is what I want possible?

Tags: .htaccess

Here is my .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress 

Redirect 301 http://whattodoindublin.com/ http://www.whattododirectory.com/category/dublin/
```

http://whattodoindublin.com/ is pointing to the same folder as http://www.whattododirectory.com/ so it loads of the same content but I want http://whattodoindublin.com/ to load the subdirectory as above , is this possible?

Comment: Switch on `RewriteLog` (2.2) or `LogLevel` (2.4). mod_rewrite will log what it is doing.

Answer (score 1):

From [Redirect Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)

> Syntax:   Redirect [status] URL-path URL
>   ...
>   The old URL-path is a case-sensitive (%-decoded) path **beginning with a slash**. A relative path is not allowed.

You can only redirect a *path* to an external URL. Maybe in your virtual host section or in the .htaccess for whattodoindublin.com, you can do

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.whattododirectory.com/category/dublin/
```